# I need to calculate a percentage in a partial, then put it into a progress bar (Bootstrap)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of an individual goal thumbnail, then use that in a Bootstrap progress bar. To calculate the percentage, I find the number of books they have already read (@user.books.count), divide it by the amount that they want to read (goal.amount), and multiply it by 100 to get a percent. Here's what I have so far:

**show.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Your goals") %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <h2 class = "top-5-margins">Your Goals</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5">
    <%= link_to "New goal", add_goal_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-default green-hover" %>
  </div>
</div>
<% if @user.goals.any? %>
    <div class="row">
            <%= render @user.goals %>
    </div>
<% else %>
    <p class = "center">You don't have any goals set. You should make one now.</p>
<% end %>
```

**_goal.html.erb:**

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="caption">
        <h3 class = "center"><%= goal.title %></h3>
        <div class="progress">
            <% @percentage = @user.books.count/goal.amount * 100 %>
            <% puts @percentage %>
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow=<%=@percentage.to_s%> aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style=<%= "width" + @percentage.to_s + "%;"%>><%= @percentage.to_s %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3><%= @user.books.count %> out of <%= goal.amount %></h3></span>
    <h4>Created on: <%= goal.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I look at the page, the progress bars don't have any progress and the value of @percentage seems to be 0.

[image: An individual goal]

*I know you're supposed to put your calculations and variables inside the controller (put the assignment of @percentage in the controller) but I don't know how I could make it work.

Comment: this could just me a formatting thing, but it should be "width:" you just have "width" in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling @user.books.count it is returning an integer. You need to convert this to a float. Or you could save the goal amount as a float.

```
>> count = 5
=> 5 
>> goal = 10
=> 10
>> count/goal
=> 0
```

Comment: What I did: `@percentage = @user.books.count.to_f/goal.amount.to_f`